# CSS Flex: How to get equal heights in flex rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I experience some difficulties in getting a flex layout with equal column heights. I have a container (`.row-container`) that contains some rows (`.flex-row`). These rows contain some content of different length. I want all rows to have equal height. As far as my flex understanding goes, I have to set `flex: display` and the `flex-direction` in the parent (`.row-container`) and `flex-grow: 1` in the children (`.flex-row`). However, the rows do not have equal height, see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m0rs8bn4/). Any ideas (and perhaps an explanation) on how to make this work?

```css
.row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-wrapper {}

.col-1,
.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.col-right {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-div">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">X</div>
        <div class="col-2">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">XXX</div>
        <div class="col-2">some longer content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">aa ab</div>
        <div class="col-2">Amet illo distinctio facilis blanditiis alias. Explicabo dolores asperiores ducimus aut officiis, vero? Accusantium in accusantium ipsa iusto velit? Quas nesciunt ipsam amet impedit adipisci odio Omnis nemo perspiciatis quibusdam</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note: In my application, I also do some "column flexing" in the `row-container`. This code is ommitted apart from the flex centering.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flex-grow` works this way: it takes available space and distributes it only after applying `flex-basis` (which when `auto` takes its value from `width` or `height`, in current case it's `height` because of `flex-direction: column`). In current case `flex-basis` is `auto` because `height` is `also`. If after applying `flex-basis` no free space will remain, `flex-grow` won't work.

So you have several options here: set `height: 0` or set `flex-basis: 0`. Also you might need `min-height: 0` (because `min-height: auto` in some cases don't allow flex-item to occupy less then its content).

Demo:

```css
.row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.flex-row {
  border: 1px solid black;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
  /* or height: 0; */
  /* if needed add min-height: 0; */
  display: flex;
  background-color: yellow;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-1,
.col-2 {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.col-right {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="some-div">
  <div class="row-container">
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">X</div>
        <div class="col-2">some content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">XXX</div>
        <div class="col-2">some longer content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-row">
      <div class="col-wrapper">
        <div class="col-1">aa ab</div>
        <div class="col-2">Amet illo distinctio facilis blanditiis alias. Explicabo dolores asperiores ducimus aut officiis, vero? Accusantium in accusantium ipsa iusto velit? Quas nesciunt ipsam amet impedit adipisci odio Omnis nemo perspiciatis quibusdam</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Also I would recommend to add some `overflow` value to specify behaviour, e.g. `overflow-y: auto`, for `.flex-row`.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is setting all the `flex` items (`.flex-row`) to have the same baseline height and allow them to grow equally to each other.

e.g.

```
.flex-row {
   flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

To maybe make it easier to understand:

```
.flex-row {
   flex-grow: 1;
   flex-basis: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0; //not needed anyway because you have a base height of 0, so they'll never need to shrink
}
```

With this, however, you run the risk that if the content-defined height of your three flex-rows is taller than `300px` - that of your `row-container`, then each row will be given `100px` in height and the content could overflow out of of the `.flex-row`

Comment: Thanks. `flex-basis: 0` was indeed the missing bit.

Answer (score 0):

`.flex-row>*{height:100px;}`
Something like this?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of a weird behaviour here, but you actually just need to set a height on the rows, even if that height is 0. Try

```
.flex-row {
    height: 0;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. `height: 0` indeed works. I learned a new trick today :) Thanks.

Comment: While height: 0 does indeed work for said case, keep in mind it will break vertical centering.